# Issue when updating date in db table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm working on a codeigniter project and I'm trying to troubleshoot a sql issue. I have a query that updates a date field in my table and it's not updating it at all.

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
  `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `state` char(2) DEFAULT '',
  `zip` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `blurb` blob,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paypal_acct_num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `progress_bar` enum('full','half','none') DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_pages` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_conversions` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_given` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `conversion_percentage` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `avg_contribution` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and when I run this query to insert data, it runs fine and sets the date to `2012-11-01`

```
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `end_date`) VALUES ('John', 'Smith2', '2012-11-01');
```

Then I get the customer_id and try to run this query

```
UPDATE `Customer` SET `end_date` = '2012-14-01' WHERE `customer_id` = '18';
```

and it sets the date end_date field to `0000-00-00`.

Why is it changing the end date to 0000-00-00 rather than 2012-14-01?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2012-14-01` is first day of fourteenth month :)

(so its invalid date, thus casted to `0000-00-00` and `Data truncated for column 'end_date' at row 1` warning was returned by mysql, which you can see by querying `SHOW WARNINGS` to mysql immediately after badly behaving query)

`2012-01-14` is 14th of January.

Comment: Could be confusing for Americans :p where the standard date format used to be YYYY/MM/DD :)

Comment: @Prof83: `2012-01-14` *is* `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Ok so you're saying that the mysql format for date is yyyy-mm-dd ?

Comment: exactly. and its generally the best format for storing dates as string, as it sorts properly using normal lexicographical order

Comment: @Andriy M Sorry hahaha i meant YYYY/DD/MM

Comment: Ok good to know. I think i had it that way at one point, but thought it was changed.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
 UPDATE `Customer` SET `end_date` = date('Y-m-d') WHERE `customer_id` = '18';
```

Use date function to update this field.

Comment: I don't want todays date in there though.

Comment: date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) - Read up on PHP timestamps